# Vuejs setting an array

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

If I set to Vue.data array like this `[0: Object, 2: Object];`
I will get in Vue console log panel array like this  `[0: Object, 1: undefined 2: Object];`
and after iteration in `'v-for="cell in row.cells"'` I got the problem of getting any property of undefined.

I resolved my problem like this:

```
v-for="cell in row.cells" v-bind:colspan="cell.colspan" v-if="typeof cell !== 'undefined'"



v-for="cell in row.cells" v-bind:colspan="cell.colspan" v-if="typeof cell !== 'undefined'"
```

I want to get in Vue array as I've tried to set without index shift or any array changings.

Answer (score 3):

Vue can iterate Objects the same as they do Arrays, if you insist on named values why not do this:

```
cells: {
  0: {},
  1: {},
  2: {}
}
```

If you got unwanted "data" in your array, you could say the following.

```
const filteredCells = row.cells.filter(cell => cell !== undefined)
```

and then iterate the **filteredCells** instead, id make filteredCells a computed value.

```
v-for="cell in filteredCells"
```

Keep index:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      row: {
        cells: [
          {name: 'peter'}, 
          {name: 'louise'}, 
          {name: 'hans'}, 
          undefined, 
          {name: 'mia'}, 
          {name: 'john'}
        ]
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredCellsWithIndex() {
      if (!this.row || !this.row.cells) {
        return
      }

      const { cells } = this.row

      return cells.map((cell, index) => {
        if (cell === undefined) {
          return
        }

        cell.yourIndex = index
        return cell
       }).filter(cell => cell !== undefined)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But after filter array you will kill indexes [0 => 1, 1 => undefined , 2 => 2] => [0 => 1, 1 => 2] I want to save my indexes

Comment: Run through the array, add the index to the object, then chain filter() afterwards, to remove undefined, and then delete your v-if on iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to cleanly remove your undefined values without making your template overly complicated.

## Create a filter.

```
v-for="cell in row.cells | isDefined"
```

```
{
  filters: {
    isDefined(items) {
      return items.filter(it => it !== undefined)
    }
  }
}
```

## Or use a computed property.

```
v-for="cell in cells"
```

```
{
  computed: {
    cells() {
      return this.row.cells.filter(it => it !== undefined)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The wish to keep index values for each property as they were in the original array, doesen't get solved with this.

Comment: If OP NEEDED index values, the template would use `for (cell,index) in ...`  OP can simply use indexOf(cell) to get index if needed.

Comment: No, ['a', 'b', undefined, 'd'], he still wants 'd' to be of index 3, your solution (as I suggested as well at first) will make 'd' using (cell, index) to index 2.